# How to remove unwanted blank page and symbol

Tags: blank-page

I am using the following document class to write a thesis for my university. Everything is provided as a template and, if possible, I wouldn't want to change much to avoid changing standard formatting.

```
\documentclass[
            a4paper, 
            12pt, 
            bibliography=totoc,                         
            parskip=half, 
            numbers=noenddot,
            captions=tableheading,      
          ]{scrreprt}
```

At the end of some chapters, not all of them, I get, a non-blank blank page. Let me explain. I get a page with header and footer and only one symbol on it that looks like a capital I.

[image: Non-blank blank page]

I have tried to see what is done differently between the chapters where I get this blank page and those which are ok and I cannot find any differences.

Has this happened to anyone before in this manner? Can anyone advise me on how to solve it? I have found questions regarding entirely blank pages for the book class because of page numbering but nothing exactly like this.

Comment: I think these blank pages related to end of chapter in right page of the 'book' and so are automatically added to let the new chapter begin on a right page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: That looks like an error somewhere in some code you have not shown, but you would need to post a small example document that produced such a page.

Comment: If your template has a documentation check for something like an "intentionally left blank page" or similar. Some people like those pages, maybe the template creator was one of them.

Comment: Problem solved. While editing to provide a MWE I stumbled upon a (very stupid) error.